# How to decode url from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, html

inside `token.php` i have this code:

```
$url = file_get_contents($urlPost);
preg_match('/\"amplem\":"(.*)\",/', $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

This `echo $matches[1]` will print out a url like this one:

`https://example.com/?id\u003dg596c2f91a67e518\u0026itag\u003d18\u0026source\u003dtest`.

on `index.php` i do a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:siteURL+'/token.php',
  data:{token:token},
  success:function(data){
    var i = decodeURIComponent(data);
    console.log(i);
  }
})
```

Current result of `console.log(i)`:

`https://example.com/?id\u003dg596c2f91a67e518\u0026itag\u003d18\u0026source\u003dtest`.

Desired result of `console.log(i)`:

`https://example.com/?id=g596c2f91a67e518&itag=18&source=test`.

**Edit -** If i put the encoded url directly inside the `decodeURIComponent();` i get the desired result, but it does not work with the url returned from the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unescape` with `JSON.stringify`:

```js
var i = "https://example.com/?id\u003dg596c2f91a67e518\u0026itag\u003d18\u0026source\u003dtest";

console.log(unescape(JSON.stringify(i)));
```

Comment: When i put the url direcly on the `var i =` it works, but it does not works when i do `var i = data`

Comment: But what is `data` then?

Comment: What is the *value* of `data`? What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: The same as `console.log(i);`, With your code i got duble backslash `https://example.com/?id\\u003dg596c2f91a67e518\\u0026itag\u003d18\\u0026source\\u003dtest`

Comment: So why does `console.log(i)` show a different response to `console.log(data)` if `i` ***is*** `data`?

Comment: I did not said it's showing different results, it's the same, because the function `decodeURIComponent()` is not decoding the url,

Comment: But if `i` is `decodeURIComponent(data)`, then execute my code upon `decodeURIComponent(data)`.

Comment: I got the same result.